# MySQL database is not updating data

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Attached is my program:

**HTML:**

```
        <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor            sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="converts.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="alert alert-error"><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?>
                        <style>
                            .alert {
                                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;
                                font-size: 13px;
                                line-height: 20px;
                                margin-bottom: 20px;
                                text-shadow: none;
                                position: relative;
                                background-color: #272e3b;
                                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
                                border: 1px solid #000;
                                box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #363d49 inset, 0 5px 10px      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                            }
                            .alert-error {
                                color: #f00;
                                background-color: #360e10;
                                box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #551e21 inset, 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                            }
                            .alert:empty{
                                display: none;
                            }
                            .alert-success {
                                color: #21ec0c;
                                background-color: #15360e;
                                box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2a551e inset, 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                            }
                        </style>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Address *" id="address" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter address here."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="cell district *" id="district" required data-validation-required-message="Enter district here.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="register" class="btn btn-xl"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

**PHP:**

```
               <?php
             session_start();
              $_SESSION['message'] = '';
               $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');
               // Check for empty fields
               if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
                empty($_POST['email'])     ||
                empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
                   empty($_POST['address'])   ||
                 !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                 {
                      echo "No arguments Provided!";
                  return false;
                   }

                 $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
                $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
                 $phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
                  $address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));

                // Create the email and send the message
               $to = 'laolufasanya@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
               $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
               $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail:                         $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nAddress:\n$address";
                  $headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
                  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
                  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
                 return true;         
                    ?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
            $(function() {

             $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var district = $("input#district").val();
            var address = $("textarea#address").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            console.log(window);
            $.ajax({
                url: window.origin + "/converts.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    address: address,
                    district: district
                    },
                cache: false,
                success: function(res)  {
                   console.log(res);
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

            $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                 $(this).tab("show");
                });
             });


               /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
                 $('#name').focus(function() {
              $('#success').html('');
           });
```

All the queries are not updating. I have been trying to get this done, nothing is working. I have pretty much tried everything in the book.

Actual PHP code:

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
 //connection to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');


if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// sql to create table
//$sql = "CREATE TABLE Added (
//id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
//name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//district VARCHAR(50),
//reg_date TIMESTAMP
//)";

//if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//echo "Table Added created successfully";
//} else {
//echo "Error creating table: " . $mysqli->error;
//}



//update database
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    //two passwords are equal to each other

    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
    $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $district = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['district']);
//make sure file type is image

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Added (name, email, phone, address, district) "
        . "VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$district')";
   var_dump($sql);
       die();

    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }




}

Help would be highly regarded on this issue, Thank you.

I have tried everything and it just keeps taking my time.
```

Help would be highly regarded on this issue, Thank you.

```
I have tried everything and it just keeps taking my time.
```

- I believe i have followed all the rules on  how to get this done but
  i keep                                                         facing
  the stumbling block, hopefully this can all be sorted out by your
  help.

  I have inserted a php code earlier but that doesn't cut it,  this is the actual code that has created a table on my database. It kinda
  shows that each content is being updated but the values remain empty.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825458/php-issues-with-mail/45825639#45825639

Comment: I don't see any mysql queries in this code - I wouldn't expect it to update any tables.

Comment: There is literally zero MySQL code in here. All this does is send email.

Comment: Pardon me, This is the actual PHP code:

Comment: Regarding the code you've added as an answer, and which I expect you will add into the question, what does the `var_dump()` give you? Note that the `die()` will obviously terminate the script, so the code cannot continue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also for the sake of the lords of Westeros https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: I have removed var_dump() and die(). I still get nothing on my table

Answer (score 0):

You're calling die() right before your query. Nothing after that is going to get executed. Try removing that line.